# Debugging Installing LXML for Python 2.x on Windows

Tags: python, windows, lxml

I have absolutely no experience programming Python, but I'm trying to set up some modules to implement [this project](https://github.com/hbrands/jira-issues-importer), and am seriously struggling with lxml. I've hunted through a lot of help forums trying to figure out how to go about getting lxml set up, and none of the solutions have helped so far.

**Things I've tried:**

Downloading the lxml file from [this website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). I'm running Python 2.7.9, and have tried using both cp27 files from that website. Both give me the same message:

```
lxml-4.3.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

After more hunting, it seemed like the command:

```
python -m pip install lxml
```

should be a viable alternative. However, this leads to these error messages (not the full output for space conservation, but this struck me as the relevant parts) :

```
c:\users\aeon~1.wil\appdata\local\temp\xmlXPathInityhhfkk.c(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory

*********************************************************************************

Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

*********************************************************************************

error: command 'C:\\Users\\aeon.williams\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I downloaded the libxml2 wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libxml-python), and ran the ...cp27-none-win32.whl successfully. I tried to run python -m pip install lxml again after this, but still got the same error message.

I'm sure I'm struggling because of how little I understand Python modules and pip, but I'm not exactly sure what direction to go in now to try to get lxml working on my computer. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Just for perspective, you're going to a lot of trouble to install a very old python so you can use a github repo that has 10 stars and hasn't been active in 2 years.

Comment: I agree, and this was my last resort...figured it wasn't worth any more hours of research and debugging, but it became a matter of pride and wanting to see if there was an easier solution I was missing because of my lack of Python experience.

Comment: It's really more of a Visual C++ question, you need those dev libraries into your build tool somehow. I imagine a modern python install will make that easy,